Not able to add comments to cell with VBA
I have a spreadsheet of stocks to track dividends. Since my tracker sheet has several columns, I want to add notes about research I am doing on another sheet which I could then display as a hover over comment in the ticker symbol cell.  I have looked at how to on this board and others and created this sub.
Sub AddComments()
    Dim rCell As Range, rEnd As Range, strNote As String, rLookupTable As Range
    Dim wsPortolio As Worksheet, wsTracker As Worksheet
    
    Set wsPortolio = Worksheets("Stock List")
    Set wsTracker = Worksheets("Tracking")
    Set rLookupTable = wsPortolio.Range("A3:H100")
    With wsTracker.Range("A3:A100")
        Set rEnd = .Find(What:="End", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    For Each rCell In wsTracker.Range("A3:A" & rEnd.Row - 1)
        With rCell
            strNote = Application.VLookup(rCell, rLookupTable, 8, False)
            If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then .Comment.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Text Text:=strNote
        End With
    Next
    Set rCell = Nothing
End Sub

When I run the code, it does populate strNote with expected values and seemed to add comments to all the ticker cells. But the little comment arrows were red. And when I looked at the Review tab/Show Comments, there are no comments except my manually entered test comment in another column. (For comments I add manually, the arrow is purple and the comment shows on mouse hover.)

See Range.AddCommentThreaded for adding a threaded comment.

Thanks @BigBen. Works perfectly to add a acomment. Now I jsut need to find out why If Not .Comment Is Nothing. I'll see what I can find out. May be a question for another thread.

Try If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then .CommentThreaded.Delete.

Thanks @taller. Just found it on my own and came back to add results.

There are two different objects in M365.
Sub Macro1()
    Range("G1").AddCommentThreaded ("Comment: test")
    Range("K1").AddComment
    Range("K1").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("K1").Comment.Text Text:="Note: test"
End Sub

Comments are indicated by a purple marker, while notes have a red marker. Both display text when you hover the mouse over them.
I believe the main source of confusion is that the Notes object was previously referred to as a Comment in earlier versions of Excel. eg. How to Add Cell Comments in Excel 2016


That is a good clarification and will hopefully clear up some confusion for others. Thanks.
